# Push images into docker hub and deploy in aws cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, github-actions, amazon-ecs, dockerhub, cicd

I am trying to deploy my application into aws cluster as follows
Steps

1. Build image and push into docker hub (it is working)
2. Deploy the image into aws cluster (I couldn't make it work)

I searched in google, but couldn't find any solution.
Here is my GitHub workflow file
`deploy.yml`. Any help is appreciated to make it work.

```yaml
# This is a basic workflow that is manually triggered

name: Deploy Manual

# Controls when the action will run. Workflow runs when manually triggered using the UI
# or API.
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "deploy"
  deploy:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
      KUBE_CONFIG_DATA: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
      KUBE_NAMESPACE: production
      DOCKER_USER: ${{secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME}}
      DOCKER_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.DOCKER_HUB_ACCESS_TOKEN}}                                                                                               
      RELEASE_IMAGE: ucars/ucars-ui3:${{ github.sha }}

    steps:
    # This step instructs Github to cancel any current run for this job on this very repository.
    - name: Cancel Previous Runs               
      uses: styfle/cancel-workflow-action@0.4.1
      with:                                    
        access_token: ${{ github.token }}   
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: docker login
      run: |
        docker login -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD 
    - name: Build the Docker image
      run: docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag $RELEASE_IMAGE
      
    - name: Docker Push
      run: docker push $RELEASE_IMAGE

    - name: Deploy to Kubernetes cluster                                                                            
      uses: kodermax/kubectl-aws-eks@master                   
      with:                                                                                                         
        args: set image deployment/ucars-ui3-pod app=${{ env.RELEASE_IMAGE }} --record -n $KUBE_NAMESPACE
```

It is failing at the step `Deploy to Kubernetes cluster`
[image: Failing Message]

```
2022-01-14T18:22:14.4557590Z ##[group]Run kodermax/kubectl-aws-eks@master
2022-01-14T18:22:14.4558128Z with:
2022-01-14T18:22:14.4559002Z   *** set image deployment/***-ui3-pod app=***/***-ui3:3d23d9fb07a2ce43b3a27502359c1a0685705200 --record -n $KUBE_NAMESPACE
2022-01-14T18:22:14.4559708Z ***
2022-01-14T18:22:14.4560253Z   IMAGE_TAG: 3d23d9fb07a2ce43b3a27502359c1a0685705200
2022-01-14T18:22:14.4608584Z   KUBE_CONFIG_DATA: ***

2022-01-14T18:22:14.4609135Z   KUBE_NAMESPACE: production
2022-01-14T18:22:14.4609639Z   DOCKER_USER: ***
2022-01-14T18:22:14.4610253Z   DOCKER_PASSWORD: ***
2022-01-14T18:22:14.4610915Z   RELEASE_IMAGE: ***/***-ui3:3d23d9fb07a2ce43b3a27502359c1a0685705200
2022-01-14T18:22:14.4611509Z ##[endgroup]
2022-01-14T18:22:14.4809817Z ##[command]/usr/bin/docker run --name a74655ce21da3d4675874b9544657797b0_b31db8 --label 9916a7 --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e IMAGE_TAG -e KUBE_CONFIG_DATA -e KUBE_NAMESPACE -e DOCKER_USER -e DOCKER_PASSWORD -e RELEASE_IMAGE -e INPUT_ARGS -e HOME -e GITHUB_JOB -e GITHUB_REF -e GITHUB_SHA -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER -e GITHUB_RUN_ID -e GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER -e GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS -e GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT -e GITHUB_ACTOR -e GITHUB_WORKFLOW -e GITHUB_HEAD_REF -e GITHUB_BASE_REF -e GITHUB_EVENT_NAME -e GITHUB_SERVER_URL -e GITHUB_API_URL -e GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL -e GITHUB_REF_NAME -e GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED -e GITHUB_REF_TYPE -e GITHUB_WORKSPACE -e GITHUB_ACTION -e GITHUB_EVENT_PATH -e GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_ACTION_REF -e GITHUB_PATH -e GITHUB_ENV -e RUNNER_OS -e RUNNER_ARCH -e RUNNER_NAME -e RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE -e RUNNER_TEMP -e RUNNER_WORKSPACE -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN -e ACTIONS_CACHE_URL -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/***-ui3/***-ui3":"/github/workspace" 9916a7:4655ce21da3d4675874b9544657797b0 set image deployment/***-ui3-pod app=***/***-ui3:3d23d9fb07a2ce43b3a27502359c1a0685705200 --record -n $KUBE_NAMESPACE
2022-01-14T18:22:14.7791749Z base64: invalid input
```

Comment: What error are you getting? you will have to provide more info than this

Comment: @RakeshGupta I have added the error logs. Could you have a look at it ?

Comment: Are you able to pull this image locally with docker pull, could be the case that the image is corrupt or something

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the issue, apparently, KUBE_CONFIG_DATA is invalid. Your entrypoint.sh in kodermax/kubectl-aws-eks@master image is trying to decode it, but can't and throwing the error.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

# Extract the base64 encoded config data and write this to the KUBECONFIG
echo "$KUBE_CONFIG_DATA" | base64 -d > /tmp/config
export KUBECONFIG=/tmp/config

sh -c "kubectl $*"
```

Please fix the KUBE_CONFIG_DATA, it must be in a valid base64 format. if you put raw kubeconfig file there, you may have to convert it to base64 format first.

```
KUBE_CONFIG_DATA: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
```